# Port Forwarding - Apache listen at port 72 or any works fine but in port 80 doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, router, port-forwarding

My apache is running on port 80. When I go to router setting and set the port forwarding from 80 to port 80 in my lan ip of my computer, it doesn't work remote. But if I change the apache to port 72 or any other port and set the port forwarding to these port, it works fine.

I'm a bit confused about it. It sound like my router use this port 80 also, but may be I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention, what router you are using. If your router has a web interface (which I guess, it has), then it is using the port 80 for it's web management interface and listening to incoming request. So when you want to forward port 80, it is possible that it won't work the way you expect. Some routers won't even allow to add such a rule.

What you can do is, try to change your router remote management web interface to be available on a different port (8080 for example), if possible. Some router has this option available under administration or management settings.

Comment: Hi sry, my router is technicolor tc7110.b, i tried to find some place to change the port 80, but i can't  :( .